# SSRS 2012, data overlat issue on top of image

Tags: reporting-services, report

I am trying to display data on top of image and can't use watermark/background image for the scenario. In crystal we can use data on top of image and set the property for image gobackward and for data fields cometofront, so that it will display the image and data together. But in SSRS the data is displaying below the image. Please help me to display the data on top of image, and I have multiple images to the displayed in a single report with data.

Comment: In the past I have used a background image on the page its self , see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239334.aspx there are limitations with this approach

Comment: If my answer helped at all I would appreciate it if you marked it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell that you want an image in. Then Click properties. Then click fill. Then change image source to 'embedded'. Then import your image.